# Can't connect with OpenSSH sftp with custom port

Tags: cygwin, sftp, openssh

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7. I have installed OpenSSH client and i am using it connect to Ubuntu server installed on virtualbox through localhost. I am connecting through ssh with this command:

```
ssh -p 3022 root@127.0.0.1
```

But when I try to use the same command to connect through sftp I get this message:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname 3022: Name or service not known
>   Connection closed

The command I am using is this

```
sftp -p 3022 root@127.0.0.1
```

Any idea why I am able to connect through ssh but not through sftp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with `sftp`, the `-p` switch has a different meaning. It means "always preserve times". It's an argument-less switch, so the following `3022` is interpreted as a standalone argument (=host name).

To set a custom port, use `-P` switch (capital P), supported by OpenSSH 5.4p1 and newer:

```
sftp -P 3022 root@127.0.0.1
```

With older versions of OpenSSH use:

```
sftp -o Port=3022 root@127.0.0.1
```

Beware that in some older versions of OpenSSH, the `-P` had yet another meaning.